# [Puppet]Environment variable in epp template

Tags: environment-variables, puppet

I'll try use $server_facts['environment'] in epp template, but he dont work correct. 
My epp code:

```
<% if $::facts[environment] == 'production' { -%>
# this is production server
<% } else { -%>
# this is NOT production server
<% } -%>
```

code run without error but always use section after `else`. Please help fix it.

Comment: Print out the current value in the template: `<%= $::facts[environment] %>`. Also, is it server_facts or facts you want?

Comment: 1) variable return empty value
2) server_facts (value from puppet.conf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all work fine after use `$::facts[agent_specified_environment]`:

```
<% if $::facts[agent_specified_environment] == 'production' { -%>
# this is production server
<% } else { -%>
# this is NOT production server
<% } -%>
```